# Function that multiplies each element of one list with four elements of second list in a loop to get a new list

Tags: python, list, multiplication

I have two lists,one of length 40 and the other of length 10.I want to multiply first four elements of the 40 list with the first element of the second list and loop that for the entire first list of 40 to a get a new list which is the product of these two.
Any suggestions on how to go about this?

```
from itertools import zip_longest
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

v=[[a1/ b1 for a1 in a4] for a4, b1 in zip(grouper(active, 4), passive)]
```

```
active=[56.93977737426758,
 54.12062072753906,
 54.89398765563965,
 55.214101791381836,
 54.29464149475098,
 53.80845832824707,
 54.46353721618652,
 54.49761962890625,
 53.01671028137207,
 53.872962951660156,
 53.156455993652344,
 53.20746994018555,
 52.529762268066406,
 56.03120040893555,
 54.122426986694336,
 55.83853149414063,
 53.51207160949707,
 54.82537269592285,
 53.569284439086914,
 53.5296745300293,
 54.354637145996094,
 54.313310623168945,
 53.26720809936523,
 54.64541053771973,
 55.00912475585938,
 55.093666076660156,
 55.138763427734375,
 54.19987297058106,
 54.07197189331055,
 53.18226623535156,
 53.656246185302734,
 54.97188377380371,
 55.28757095336914,
 54.08882141113281,
 53.08153915405274,
 53.61944770812988,
 53.15986633300781,
 53.53702735900879,
 53.32623863220215,
 52.01462173461914]
```

```
passive= [54.46392059326172,
 52.37292861938477,
 51.95756149291992,
 53.40110778808594,
 54.46831512451172,
 56.04657173156738,
 57.74487495422363,
 53.75052452087402,
 56.246402740478516,
 55.15713691711426]
```

My current output is a list of 10.I want a list of 40.I want to take divide the first four elements of active with first element of passive...and so on.In the end I want a new list of 40 elements and not 10.
example [active1/passive1,active2/passive1,active3/passive1....active40/passive10]

```
[[1.0454586587604597,
  0.9936967470945319,
  1.0078963662125922,
  1.0137739110579735],
 [1.0366928664488493,
  1.0274097658218595,
  1.0399177333006342,
  1.040568497228071],
 [1.020384882546816,
  1.0368647296698332,
  1.0230744951511204,
  1.0240563338877238],
 [0.9836830066620091,
  1.0492516490722763,
  1.013507569945381,
  1.045643691807429],
 [0.9824440408551517,
  1.0065553261670555,
  0.9834944282126284,
  0.982767218109524],
 [0.9698119879004422,
  0.9690746274955083,
  0.9504097477092123,
  0.9750000553011796],
 [0.9526234977470646,
  0.954087546649548,
  0.9548685224696527,
  0.9386092361191739],
 [1.005980357871888,
  0.9894278559960512,
  0.9982460015709302,
  1.0227227411047006],
 [0.9829530113857514,
  0.9616405454531767,
  0.9437321600631335,
  0.9532955903958973],
 [0.9637894441999811,
  0.9706273811757119,
  0.9668057773255447,
  0.9430261366318299]]
```

​

Comment: Sample lists with what you have already tried would boost your chances of getting valid answers.

Comment: Can we see some code? Give it a shot.

Comment: Multiply them how? 1*1, 2*1, 3*1, 4*1 or 1*2*3*4*1? (Both lists being natural numbers sequences starting in 1)

Comment: a=[1,2,3,.....40]
len(a)=40
b=[1,2,....10]
len(b)=10

Comment: I want to make two lists,one by multiplying & other by dividing ->every first four element of a[ ] with the every element of b [ ] in loop.
So something like : [1,2,3,4]/1 -> will be the first element of my new list.
The second will be [5,6,7,8]/2 and so on.I hope this makes clear.
The last element of the new set would be [37,38,39,40]/10.
The above example was for division operator.I want to repeat the same thing with multiplication.

Comment: @Aran-Fey just posted

Comment: Uh, what? Where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For e.g.

```
a = range(40)
b = range(10)
```

Simplest:

```
[x * b[i//4] for i, x in enumerate(a)]
```

More functional:

```
# from https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes
from itertools import zip_longest
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

[a1 * b1 for a4, b1 in zip(grouper(a, 4), b) for a1 in a4]
```

Comment: I just posted a sample comment above,I tried this out but I am unfortunately not getting the desired result.

Comment: @mashedpoteto Looks like the desired result to me. If this isn't what you want, show us what is that you want and explain how this is different from that. (And don't do it in comments... edit it into your question.)

Comment: Rolled back because the first solution was actually the correct one (yielding a list of 40 numbers, not a list 10 lists of 4); "Not getting the desired result" - you should be more specific how the "desired result" differs from the one obtained by my code.

Comment: @Amadan it worked.Initially the problem was a very simple error on how I wrote the code,which gave a division by zero error.Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using pure Python in one line:

```
newList = [active[j] / passive[i] for i in range(len(passive)) for j in range(i*4,i*4+4)]
for elem in newList:
    print(elem)
```

This will print:

```
1.0454586587604597
0.9936967470945319
1.0078963662125922
1.0137739110579735
1.0366928664488493
1.0274097658218595
1.0399177333006342
1.040568497228071
1.020384882546816
1.0368647296698332
1.0230744951511204
1.0240563338877238
0.9836830066620091
1.0492516490722763
1.013507569945381
1.045643691807429
0.9824440408551517
1.0065553261670555
0.9834944282126284
0.982767218109524
0.9698119879004422
0.9690746274955083
0.9504097477092123
0.9750000553011796
0.9526234977470646
0.954087546649548
0.9548685224696527
0.9386092361191739
1.005980357871888
0.9894278559960512
0.9982460015709302
1.0227227411047006
0.9829530113857514
0.9616405454531767
0.9437321600631335
0.9532955903958973
0.9637894441999811
0.9706273811757119
0.9668057773255447
0.9430261366318299
```

Same goes for multiplying:

```
newList = [active[j] * passive[i] for i in range(len(passive)) for j in range(i*4,i*4+4)]
```